# Polar plot and coding for pi/3

Tags: maple

In polar coordinates, you must create the following graph

1) How to write the code for the line theta=pi/3 in Maple?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Mathematica or any of the other Wolfram Research software for which questions are accepted on this site.

Comment: This is not a site for Maple questions. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In maple, you should search `polarplot`

```
restart:
with(plots):
polarplot(Pi/3);
```

[image]

In *Mathematica*, you can also use `PolarPlot`,

```
PolarPlot[Pi/3, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```